# Graphical connection between two matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to show the connection of an element of a matrix, with a column on another matrix, like this:

[image: Sparse matrix Save on coordinate method]

How i can do this?

Comment: can you post your matrix code?

Comment: A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 
\end{matrix}
\right] @percusse

Comment: @meysam And what about the code for the matrices on the right side?

Comment: It's my problem too! @GonzaloMedina

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option using `\tikzmark` from the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand\BoxMatrix[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw 
  ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt]{pic cs:#1}) 
  rectangle ++(#2,2.65ex);
}
\newcommand\BoxEntry[2][fill=red!30]{
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=(O.base)]\node[draw,inner sep=2.5pt,#1] (O){#2};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill=cyan!50] 
  ([xshift=-7pt,yshift=20pt]{pic cs:topa}) 
  rectangle 
  ([xshift=13pt,yshift=-15pt]{pic cs:bottoma});
\draw[->]
  ([yshift=3pt]{pic cs:starta}) 
  to[out=80,in=90] 
  ([yshift=22pt]{pic cs:topa});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\BoxMatrix{startAAa}{3cm}
\BoxMatrix{startJRa}{3cm}
\BoxMatrix{startJBa}{3cm}

\[
A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
6 & 0 & 7 & \BoxEntry{8}\tikzmark{starta} & 9 \\ 
0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{array}{r@{\,=\ }rrr}
AA & 
\tikzmark{startAAa}12 & \tikzmark{topa}8 & 4\\[1ex]
JR &
\tikzmark{startJRa}\phantom{1}5 & 4 & 15\\[1ex]
JB &
\tikzmark{startJBa}\phantom{1}1 & \tikzmark{bottoma}13 & 6
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill=orange!50] 
  ([xshift=-7pt,yshift=20pt]{pic cs:topb}) 
  rectangle 
  ([xshift=8pt,yshift=-15pt]{pic cs:bottomb});
\draw[->]
  ([yshift=3pt]{pic cs:startb}) 
  to[out=-50,in=230] 
  ([yshift=-18pt]{pic cs:bottomb});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\BoxMatrix{startAAb}{4cm}
\BoxMatrix{startJRb}{4cm}
\BoxMatrix{startJBb}{4cm}

\vspace{1cm}

\[
A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \BoxEntry[fill=yellow]{30}\tikzmark{startb} & 0 & 12 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{array}{r@{\,=\ }rrr}
AA & 
\tikzmark{startAAb}12 & 8 & \tikzmark{topb}4\\[1ex]
JR &
\tikzmark{startJRb}\phantom{1}5 & 4 & 15\\[1ex]
JB &
\tikzmark{startJBb}\phantom{1}1 & 13 & \tikzmark{bottomb}6
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo! How i can color selected box on each section? and Can i set a fixed width for AA, JR and JC?

Comment: @meysam Please see my updated answer.

Comment: There are a few alignment problems: (1) The red square is not exactly centered relative to `8`; (2) `5` and `1` are not exactly aligned under the `2` in `12`; (3) `8` and `4` are not aligned relative to `13`; (4) the spacing after `=` is too small; (5) the boxes to the right are not exactly aligned.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg all of them fixed now (I hope).

Comment: Almost all of them are fixed; the spacing after `=` is still to small. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Arghhhh! I think it's fine now in the last edit :)

Comment: Indeed it is. I can't find any more reasons for nitpicking on your otherwise great answer. `:)`